# How to block libwww-perl access via .htaccess in nginx server

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, server

I am familiar with Apache server but new to Nginx server that's why I am little confuse about how to block libwww-perl access.
In Apache server I used this code

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
 RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside HTTP section, add these lines:

# Common bandwidth hoggers and hacking tools.

```
  if ($http_user_agent ~ "libwww-perl") {
    return 403;
  }
```